# How do you create a drag n drop expandable file browser using html5 and php

Tags: php, html, drag-and-drop, file-browser

I would like to be able to drag a directory into my browser and have it populate a file browser section to the right of the browser window with all the files and sub-directory's and their content in the file browser section.

The file browser would look something like this : [image: http://haacked.com/images/WinSCPScreenshot.gif]

Any suggestions quick and easy libraries or code snippets to get started with would be great!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Cheers all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice drag and drop demo using HTML5. PHP wouldn't really affect anything, as it is server side, and you're talking about client side interaction.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: The html5rocks.com site actually help me find the literature on file hierarchy and control over that. Thanks for the lead.